Monitor AWS ECS Fargate application with Prometheus and grafana (not managed by AWS)
I want to setup Prometheus and Grafana to monitor my existing ECS Fargate services. How can I do the setup? I can't find any proper documentation.
In my existing service task definition, I have added
Java_EMF_Metrics with a value of true and ECS_PROMETHEUS_EXPORTER_PORT with a value of 9404.
And my application is running on port 5000, so I mapped with 9404.
Now how can I install and run Prometheus and Grafana in this? What changes do i have to make in my existing application? Also, my application is running in a private subnet and can be accessed using AWS API Gateway.
Can someone please help me setting up this. I'm struggling from last 1 week for this setup.
